# Google drive api file.get gives unreadable content

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I just need to read the content of a file(no need to download the file) and store the data into my application. I am able to get the content of a file in response by using this api "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId?alt=media". But the response of this api returns an unreadble format, something like this "�dҚ�ȳ:\u0010��$���2�m��L̆���✳ŝ-�lqg�;[����O�s�\u0011�\u001bk\".

Below is the code I am using. This is Gdrive api v3.

```
drive.files.get(
  {
    fileId: fileId,
    alt: "media",
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("err = ", err);
      return false;
    }

    if (res) {
      console.log("File Details");
      console.log(res);
    }
  }
);
```

How can I get the data in readable format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading a file from Google Drive in Javascript client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839431/downloading-a-file-from-google-drive-in-javascript-client)

Comment: @DaImTo No. I am able to get the data(content of a file) in response but its not in readable format. So my question is how can I get the data in a readable(normal text) format. Thanks.

Comment: did you try downloading the file then opening it?  it comes back as binary data not text your going to have to save it first then open the file.

Comment: What is the file type? As DalmTo says, you are downloading binary content which will not be readable.

Comment: @DaImTo Is it not possible to get the content of a file in response itself rather than downloading the file. I am sorry if am asking a stupid question. I am asking this because I used the below api , it gave the actual content in response itself `drive.files.export( { fileId: fileId, mimeType: "text/plain", alt: "media", }, (err, res) => { if (err) { console.log("err = ", err); } if (res) { console.log(res.data); } } ); `

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> I used the below api , it gave the actual content in response itself

The key in that particular request is that the file mimeType is:

```
mimeType: "text/plain"
```

This means that the content of this file is just text, so you can read the contents no problem.

However, it looks like in your original question you are requesting a file that is *not* plain text. Maybe a PDF, or a Word `.doc`. These files are encoded in [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file) so their content is not readable by humans. To read the contents you need the appropriate program.

Though you haven't provided the full code, so I can't be sure what type of file you are trying to download.