# Read Google Drive file in Javascript on New Google Sites web page

Tags: javascript, drive

I have a new Google Sites web page with some Google Maps javascript to display a load of places (post offices in Somerset).  I have an XML file with the data on my Google Drive file with public access via the URL.  How do I read the Google Drive file in my Google Sites web page javascript ?

It seems like a simple thing to do, the Google Drive web page is generally accessible via the URL
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18tCKlaTfgzU0JPB0q7xQHqdQuJviOW8z/view?usp=sharing - there is nothing secret about the contents but I get stopped by the security from linking from one bit of Google to another even though the Google Sites web page is on my Google Drive.

I tried going down the Google Drive OAuth route but got into a twisty maze of web pages that just took me back to where I started - it gets to the point of "generate key" and then gives me a link that doesn't go anywhere.

At the moment I've taken the easy way out and imbedded the XML data in my web page !

Help please - it seems like it ought to be so easy but it ain't !

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839431/) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks very much but unfortunately not - it looks like the problem I have is with the OAuth authorisation and the reference above doesn't really go into that.