# Download an image from google drive api in NestJS

Tags: next.js, google-api, google-drive-api, nestjs

I'm trying to download an image from google drive API in nestJS. I'm able to get the response which is a file but it downloads as a 2 byte image as an unsupported format.
[This is my download method in the service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrtMg.png)[This is the controller where I make the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GP9e.png)

I tried to get the image from google drive
I expected to be able to download the image successfully
So it downloads the file but its size is 2 byte which should not be the case and also after previewing the file they say its unsupported format

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839431/downloading-a-file-from-google-drive-in-javascript-client
This may point you in the right direction.

Comment: Please include your code not Images